# Ext JS 3 error on joomla using ose membership component

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, joomla

Hello guys i am really frustrated trying to figure out what is wrong ...

I am using ose membership component (subscription management) on my joomla platform and i am receiving a js exeption when i try to register a new subsriber here:

http://www.destinationcrete.gr/index.php?option=com_osemsc&view=register&Itemid=1961&lang=en

The exception i receive is the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <        ext-all.js:13
Ext.util.JSON.doDecode                          ext-all.js:13
(anonymous function)                            ext-all.js:13
Ext.extend.handleResponse                       ext-all.js:21
Ext.form.Action.processResponse                 ext-all.js:21
Ext.extend.success                              ext-all.js:21
Ext.extend.handleResponse                       ext-all.js:13
f                                               ext-base.js:7
m                                               ext-base.js:7
(anonymous function)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed with this ?

Comment: **OSE Membership** is a commercial extension, therefore surely the developers provide support for it. You might be best off contacting them first ;)

Comment: in particular and if you expand ext-all.js the exact position of error is line 2585: return eval("(" + json + ")")

Comment: i have ... but no response... :(

Comment: and i am not sure that this is a matter of ose membership ...

Comment: It might be a bug so give wait for a reply from them, else post a comment on their forum if they have one.

Comment: i hope stackoverflow is going to provide better support!